# Correct syntax for constructor of single class with inheritance

Tags: constructor, mfc

Here are two approaches for the declaration of a constructor.

## Version 1

```
CAssignHistoryDlg::CAssignHistoryDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CResizingDialog(_T("SMHistory"), CAssignHistoryDlg::IDD, pParent, false)
    , m_pCombo(nullptr)
    , m_pStrText(nullptr)
    , m_pGrid(nullptr)
    , m_bBuildTreeMode(false)
    , m_bFirstSelChangeEvent(false)
    , m_iLookIn(LOOKIN_THEME_AND_METHOD) // AJT v10.7.0
    , m_bFullHistoryMode(false)
    , m_pHistoryOriginal(nullptr)
{

}
```

## Version 2

```
CAssignHistoryDlg::CAssignHistoryDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : m_pCombo(nullptr)
    , m_pStrText(nullptr)
    , m_pGrid(nullptr)
    , m_bBuildTreeMode(false)
    , m_bFirstSelChangeEvent(false)
    , m_iLookIn(LOOKIN_THEME_AND_METHOD) // AJT v10.7.0
    , m_bFullHistoryMode(false)
    , m_pHistoryOriginal(nullptr)
    , CResizingDialog(_T("SMHistory"), CAssignHistoryDlg::IDD, pParent, false)

{

}
```

The only difference is the placement of the base constructor call. Are there are rules on which way they should be specified? Does it matter?

I am not asking for "opinions" here. Just a factual response if possible.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no multiple inheritance here. You seem to be deriving form a single class, so single inheritance. Usually the only option when deriving from MFC classes.

Comment: @IInspectable Good point. Adjusted tags and reworded question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't matter, but the base class constructor is always executed before any member class initialization is done.

I place the base class constructors always on top of the list. Because it is more readable from my point of view.

Even class member initialization is not done in the sequence written in the constructor. They are initialized in the sequence of declaration in the class.